# Add pagination to the Top of Datatable

Tags: datatables

Hello guys I'm using datatable to display my tables. The thing is I want to add only the pagination box located on the right bottom at the top right of the of the table. I used this option but

```
"dom": '<"top"iflp<"clear">>rt<"bottom"iflp<"clear">>'
```

it adds the drop down box at the bottom of the table and the text

> "Showing 10 out of 57"

at the top of the table. I do not want this to happen. Can somebody tell me what to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer. I did it like this:

```
"dom": '<"top"flp<"clear">>rt<"bottom"ifp<"clear">>'
```

I just removed `i` from the top which displays the table information and `l` from the bottom which is used for pagination control.